# Checking properties on different classes

Tags: c#

I have multiple classes that all contain the same property along with a whole of different other properties. The classes don't use any kind of Interface. What I would like to do is pass an instance of each class to a method that can check for the property.

Can generics be used for this? If so, how can I construct a method to perform this task?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like a use for dynamic (in C# 4.0)

```
public void DoMethodThing (dynamic your_object){
   your_object.ThatThingYouDo();
}
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264736.aspx

Comment: And is there a way to check to see if the property exists before getting it?

Comment: I believe Dave talks about it in here: http://davefancher.com/2010/09/10/basic-dynamic-programming-in-net-4/ I'll come back a little later and see if i can find where he mentions it.

Answer (score 7):

Well, you *could* use reflection... but it would be better to use an interface which specified the property, then you could make each class implement the interface. Generics won't help you here - there's no way of specifying "T must be a type which has property X" for example.

If you're using C# 4 you *could* use dynamic typing:

```
public void Foo(dynamic d)
{
    Console.WriteLine(d.MyProperty);
}
```

However, I would advise you to try to use static typing (via interfaces) if at all possible.